# The example about native message in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to use the native message in Firefox, and I'm trying to run the example in https://www.github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/native-messaging/, but  Firefox gave me a notice says:

> "attempt to post Message on disconnected port."

I tried everything that I can, but it doesn't work. Could anybody help me?